# resx file access

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resx

When you create a new C# Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2012, It has a `Properties` folder containing a `Resources.resx` file.

How do I access this file?

I have tried:

```
ResourceManager rm=new ResourceManager("Resources.resx",typeof(MyClass).Assembly);
string s=rm.GetString("MyString");
```

But I get `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` because for some reason it appends `.resources` to the filename so it's looking for `Resources.resx.resources`.
I then appended `.resources` to the filename to see if it might actually work. It didn't, same exception, why?

I also tried using the `ResxResourceReader` class but it looks for a resx file in a directory, and this specific resx file I'm trying to access is not stored in a directory, it's compiled in to my assemblies so that doesn't seem to be helping either.

I thought it'd be really simple, maybe it is and I'm just overlooking something?

If it's not simple, I might as well create a C# class and hard-code my strings (only type of resource I need right now).

And another question: If the resx file is compiled in to your exe, does that mean you can't change it's values during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is plain simple (usually).

Use the Properties class!

```
Properties.Resources.MyString
```

The Properties folder you see in your Solution Explorer is not just a fancy folder ;p Visual Studio generates a class to access all your resources with ease.

Comment: Thanks, I used this now and I'm assuming there's no way you could change the resources values during runtime as it's a read only resource.

Comment: I'm having the same issue at work (finding a way to be able to insert a new language without having to redownload the program or something), and anyway, resx files (even though they're just disguised XML) aren't meant for runtime modification. But feel free to ask it as a new question, it could attract better answers.